# Как вытащить из БД строку с уникальным id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Добрый день.

Вопрос связан с выводом данных в таблице БД.

Допустим есть таблица следующего типа:

`id title
1 первая строка
2 вторая строка
3 третья строка`

Назовем эту таблицу table1. Выполняю SQL запрос:

```
SELECT title FROM table1 WHERE id
```

После этого в PHP после подключения к БД пишу следующий запрос к БД:

```
    $db = mysqli_connect("HOST","name","passowrd");
    mysqli_select_db($db, "name_db");
    $title = "SELECT title FROM table1 WHERE id";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $title);
    $titlerows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
```

Готово.
После этого пытаюсь вытащить строки в столбце title.
    `echo $titlerows[0];`
Покажет содержимое первого title:
    `первая строка`
Однако следующий запрос:
    `echo $titlerows[1];`
Ничего не выводит. Хотя я ожидал следующее:
    `вторая строка`
Помогите с управлением определенного столба таблицы, с возможностью выводить данные по индексам id. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вообще, что значит "WHERE id" что это за незаконченное условие..

Comment: В данном случае думаю условие можно опустить. Т.к. если применить поиск конкретной строки WHERE id= 1, то для поиска следующей строки необходим уже новый запрос.

Comment: +Если конкретная строка то надо "WHERE id=1 Limit 1;" дабы мускул после нахождения строки 1 не лазил и не искал еще одну строку с идом 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том что функция `mysqli_fetch_row()` за один вызов извлекает только одну строку из результирующей таблицы. Чтобы вытащить вторую строку, необходимо, вызвать функцию повторно. Часто, чтобы пройтись по все таблицы, организуют цикл при помощи `while`

```
$db = mysqli_connect("HOST","name","passowrd");
mysqli_select_db($db, "name_db");
$title = "SELECT title FROM table1";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $title);
while($titlerows = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
  echo $titlerows[0].'<br />';
}
```

Используя индексы массива `$titlerows`, вы можете обращаться к номерам столбцов, но не к рядам.

PS Кроме того, обратите внимание на `WHILE id` - синтаксической ошибки тут нет, но смысла в таком условии тоже не много. В текущем варианте его можно просто опустить и извлекать все строки.

Comment: Спасибо. Вывел весь список. Собственно самый важный вопрос вот какой. Как вывести не весь список, а интересующую строку. Скорее всего id тут понадобиться. Т.е. внутри функции должны быть условие по которой он будет искать все строки и если найдет id = 2 например, выведет только эту строку.

Comment: @DmitriyDoronin Если вам нужна отдельная строка SELECT title FROM table1 WHERE id = 2 - просто выполняйте запрос и один раз вызывайте mysqli_fetch_row($result), более того можно даже в конце запроса добавить LIMIT 1, чтобы ограничить вывод только одной строкой. Если вы ожидаете несколько строк - лучше всегда пробегаться по результирующей таблице циклом и формировать результирующий массив. Дальше уже работать с полученным массивом. Т.е. в цикле while() мы не выводим данные echo, а складируем нужные элементы в отдельный массив, скажем $result.

Comment: @DmitriyDoronin если вам вообще нужно только одно значение, то вместо функции mysqli_fetch_row(), лучше использовать функцию mysqli_result() - которая извлекает из результирующей таблицы не массив, а одно значение.

Comment: Хорошо. Если опустить условие WHERE, получается мы выгружаем все значения title из таблицы. При вызове цикла while выгружаются все значения. Можно ли выбирать строки по индексу полученного массива?

Comment: @DmitriyDoronin В этом случае вы должны сформировать свой массив $results = array();
while($titlerows = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
  $results[] = $titlerows[0];
} и тогда, да, вы сможете обращаться к нему по индексу $results[0], $results[1], $results[2] и т.д. Этот индекс будет обозначать именно строки в вашей результирующей таблице.